# Vuejs simplify vuex action call

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am calling a store action through a component like:

```
sublitPost(){
    this.$store.dispatch({type:"submitPost", userPost:this.newPost});
}
```

and the store action looks like this:

```
  actions: {
    submitPost({commit, state}, userPost: any) {
     /...rest code here
```

Although, I would like to simplify this and call the action like:

```
sublitPost(){
    this.$store.dispatch("submitPost", this.newPost);
}
```

What is the tweak in the action's signature I have to do? What I've tried is to have the action like:

```
  actions: {
        submitPost(userPost: any) {
          console.log({userPost})
         /...rest code here
```

but in this case, the received object doesn't look correct. What I get in the console log is:
[image]

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your syntax:

```
actions: {
    submitPost(state, data) {
      console.log(data)
    {
```

Comment: I did that and works pretty good. Thank you. Does that mean that every action should start with the "state" as the first parameter?

Comment: no, you can also called it only `submitPost(context)` and change the state or commit some mutations with `context.state` or `context.commit` etc. With `submitPost({state, commit}, data)` you can pass data and commit for example some mutations

Answer (score 1):

I have divided my store into modules so I am exporting my all mutations, actions, getters.
I am committing a mutation from my action with payload,here payload is an object with property currentWidth

```
export function fetchDeviceCurrentWidth ({ commit, state }, payload) {
  commit('updateDeviceCurrentWidth', payload)
}
```

My mutation

```
export function updateDeviceCurrentWidth (state, payload) {
  state.currentDeviceWidth = payload.currentWidth
}
```

My getter

```
export const currentDeviceWidth = state => state.currentDeviceWidth
```

This is from where I am dispatching an action:

```
myEventHandler () {
      this.$store.dispatch('fetchDeviceCurrentWidth', {
        currentWidth: window.innerWidth
      })
    }
```

There are many ways to use vuex store, but I like to break store into modules depending on features or Components.